# What is the difference between Android's strings.xml and arrays.xml?

Tags: android, xml, arrays

I need to make a string-array. Is it better to put it in `/res/values/arrays.xml` or in `/res/values/strings.xml`? Some sites say to put it in one file and some in the other. Is there a standard practice?

Comment: difference between strings.xml and arrays.xml? Well, the name suggests it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because both is possible, IMO it's all about the controversial question about clear design.
Take this example of a strings.xml, where the array `food` takes references of already specified strings:

```
<string name="burger">burger</string>
<string name="hotdog">hotdog</string>

<string-array name="food">
    <item>@string/burger</item>
    <item>@string/hotdog</item>
</string-array>
```

Now it is also possible to put the array in the same way in arrays.xml. It is up to you which way is cleaner. Arrays to arrays.xml or keep string-arrays in strings.xml, where the references of the elements are.

As another example let's say you wanna have an additional `integer-array`

```
<integer-array name="pictures_of_food">
  <item>@drawable/burger</item>
  <item>@drawable/hotdog</item>
</integer-array>
```

Because this one belongs to arrays.xml you should put the string-array at the same place.
As I said this is opinion based and other people will have another way to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `values` directory, the XML file name is up to your choosing. All of them are parsed as value resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `string-array` in to `string.xml`

```
<string-array name="system">
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
</string-array>
```

Hope this helps you!!!

if it is not working please let me know i will try to help you more.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help. I think I understand now.

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, can you please accept my answer?

Comment: Steve Benett answered with the most relevant detail to my question, so I accepted his answer. I still appreciate your willingness to help, though.